How to create multiple custom error messages using Elysia's Typebox?
I want to create a schema with Elysia's Typebox so that a different error message appears for each check.
I want to do something similar to what Joi does.
Joi:
import joi from 'joi';

export const CreateUserSchema = joi.object({
  name: joi.string().required().messages({
    'any.required': 'The name field is required.',
    'string.empty': 'The name field cannot be empty.',
  }),
  email: joi.string().email().required().messages({
    'any.required': 'The address field is required.',
    'string.email': 'The email field is invalid.',
    'string.empty': 'The address field cannot be empty.',
  }),
  password: joi.string().min(6).required().messages({
    'any.required': 'The password field is required.',
    'string.empty': 'The password field cannot be empty.',
    'string.min': 'The password field must have at least 6 characters.',
  }),
});

export type CreateUserDTO = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
};

Typebox from Elysia:
import { t, type Static } from "elysia"

export const CreateUserSchema = t.Object({
    name: t.String({
        minLength: 1,
        error: 'The name field cannot be empty.'
    }),
    email: t.String({
        format: 'email',
        error: 'The email provided is invalid.'
    }),
    password: t.String({
        minLength: 6,
        error: 'The password field cannot be less than 6 characters long.'
    })
})

export type CreateUserDTO = Static<typeof CreateUserSchema>

This is a simple example, but I want to apply this to parameters that need multiple checks
I've already tried using an array or an object inside the typebox error prop, but it simply won't accept it.

Elysia accepts function as error so you can use it like
t.Object({
  name: t.String({
    minLength: 1,
    error({ errors, type, validator, value }) {
      const error = errors[0];
      switch (error.type) {
        case ValueErrorType.ObjectRequiredProperty: {
          return 'The name field is required.';
        }
        case ValueErrorType.StringMinLength: {
          return 'The name field cannot be empty.';
        }
        default: {
          return error.message;
        }
      }
    },
  }),
})

